React Expo Project Error: Cannot find native module 'ExponentImagePicker' on iOS Device
I followed the "Get Started" guide on the Home tab in the expo website and configured my project for an iOS device development build. I am also connected to the Expo Application Services (EAS).
After getting started, I ran npm run reset-project and began following along with the "Get Started" guide in the Learn tab.
Everything was working fine until I reached the Image Picker section. I installed `expo-image-picker' and added the following lines of code in my index.tsx file:
export default function Index() {
    const pickImageAsync = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 1,
        });

        if (!result.canceled) {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            alert('You did not select any image.');
        }
    };
// the rest of the function

My project failed on my iOS device with the following error:

I do not have any errors when opening the project on the web.
Do I need to run npx expo prebuild and fix this natively on iOS or is there an easier solution?
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the dependencies.

Solved by running a new expo development build.
eas build --profile development --platform ios
